# My site is not reading the special characters "ä ö ü"

Tags: php, joomla

My site is not showing these "ä ö ü" characters.Instead of ü it shows like "端".

```
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
```

Comment: Have you set a proper charset in your html body? Something like that: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: Yes..I added this on the header.php page. <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: Sorry I meant `head` instead of body of course. If you are using an `HTML5` doctype then a `meta charset` is enough. Anyways, if static text is displayed correctly then it must be something about your database or php file. Try to *play* with [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) and [utf8_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) functions

Comment: Can you please take a look on this site:  kalari.ch  you can see the issues there..On home page look at the news section

Comment: The charset in that page is `euc-jp`... use `utf-8`...

Comment: I changed that also..But no use

Comment: To correctly display some UTF8 characters you need the right charset and the right input. Does your php file output UTF8-encoded text? Try to use those functions I mentioned some comments above. Having no code I can't help you further.